# RegEx for matching mp3 URLs

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

How can I get an mp3 url with REGEX?

This mp3 url, for example:

```
https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3
```

This is a what I've tried so far but I want it to only accept a url with '.mp3' on the end.

```
(https?|ftp|file)://[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]
```

Comment: Please use the backticks (`\``) when quoting code

Comment: that regex is correct i think your applying or checking method has a problem , provide us with more snap of the code

Comment: If you want it to match inputs ending with '.mp3' you should add `\.mp3$` at the end of your regex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This expression would likely pass your desired inputs:

```
^(https?|ftp|file):\/\/(www.)?(.*?)\.(mp3)$
```

If you wish to add more boundaries to it, you can do that. For instance, you can add a list of chars instead of `.*`.

[image]

I have added several capturing groups, just to be simple to call, if necessary.

#### RegEx

If this wasn't your desired expression, you can modify/change your expressions in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/cj8uGf/1/).

#### RegEx Circuit

You can also visualize your expressions in [jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24):

[image]

```js
const regex = /^(https?|ftp|file):\/\/(www.)?(.*?)\.(mp3)$/gm;
const str = `https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3
http://soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3
http://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3
ftp://soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3
file://localhost/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3
file://localhost/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.wav
file://localhost/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.avi
file://localhost/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.m4a`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

#### Java Test

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = "^(https?|ftp|file):\\/\\/(www.)?(.*?)\\.(mp3)$";
final String string = "https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3\n"
     + "http://soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3\n"
     + "http://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3\n"
     + "ftp://soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3\n"
     + "file://localhost/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3\n"
     + "file://localhost/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.wav\n"
     + "file://localhost/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.avi\n"
     + "file://localhost/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.m4a";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want it to match inputs ending with '.mp3' you should add `\.mp3$` at the end of your regex.

`$` indicates the end of your expression

```
(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]\.mp3$
```

#### Matching:

```
https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3 **=> Match** 
https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp4 **=> No Match**
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use anchors to assert the start `^` and the end `$` of the string and end the pattern with `.mp3`:

```
^https?://\S+\.mp3$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Assert start of string
- `https?://` Match http with optional s and `://`
- `\S+` Match 1+ times a non whitespace char
- `\.mp3` Match `.mp3`
- `$` Assert end of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aEX00b/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/070ND9)

For example:

```
String regex = "^https?://\\S+\\.mp3$";
String[] strings = {
        "https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3",
        "https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp4"
};
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
for (String s : strings) {
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
    }
}
```

Result

```
https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3
```